# Как использовать локальное хранилище и textArea js?

Tags: javascript

1. Где находится этот файл? Можно ли его скопировать к себе?
2. Как сделать `textArea`, который редактировал по ключу хранилища его значение, удалял по ключу его вовсе, добавлял новое значение по ключу!?!
3. Не будет ли В коде ошибка: `"message": "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.",`
4. Не будет ли при сравнении (значений и ключей хранилища) с переменными `var MyKey var MyValue` разница в шрифтах?
   Вот что я умею делать: (копируйте код в index.html в Mozilla Firefox без ошибок работает):
5. P.S. Не судите строго, - я новичок во всем этом. изучаю js 1-ую неделю.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <html>
    <script>
    
    var Key1 = "Areg";
    var Key2 = 1234567;
    var Key3 = "Arthur";
    localStorage["1"] = Key1;
    localStorage["2"] = Key2;
    localStorage["3"] = Key3;
    var ValueU=localStorage["1"]+"_"+localStorage["2"]; 
    alert(ValueU);      
    delete localStorage["3"];
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Скачать можно. Заходите в браузер, нажимаете на иконку слева от сайта, переходите в настройки файлов `cookie`, в нём выбираете название сайта, а в нём `localstorage`.
 2. Примеры ниже.
 3. Нет, ошибки не будет
 4. Разница переменных не влияет. А вот разница в названиях ключей влияет.
 Используйте одинаковый регистр.

Добавить и получить значение textarea:

```js
        var text = document.getElementById('text');
        var t = localStorage.getItem('text'); // Проверяем есть ли значение в localstorage
        if(t){ // Если есть
            text.value = t; // То добавляем в textarea
        }
        save.onclick = function () {
            localStorage.setItem('text', text.value); // Сохраняем значение из textarea в localstorage
        }
```

```html
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="save">Сохранить значение в localsotrage</button>
```

Замена значений происходит при помощи:

```
localStorage['text'] = 'ZZZ'; // Меняем значение
```

Удаляется значение при помощи

```
delete localStorage.text;
```

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Да можно. Если у Вас windows, то хранилище будет примерно по такому пути `C:\Users\Имя_пользователя\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`

Comment: можно ли выбрать формат локального хранилища (to set)?

Comment: @Arthur Alunts Подскажите, пожалуйста, что Вы имеете ввиду под форматом?

Comment: по этому пути лежит папка leveldb в ней зашифрованные файлы, чем их открывать?Thanks!!! Было бы неплохо открывать эти файлы в текстовом редакторе. могу ли я удалить эти файлы система не будет ругаться?

Comment: @Arthur Alunts, Да, можете удалить, при следующей записи они снова появятся. )  Открыть редактором можете. А есть и специальные утилиты для открытия подобных файлов. Для форматов .loc и .localstorage.

Comment: т.е. я могу удалить все файлы данной папки?

Comment: @Arthur Alunts, Да всё верно. Есть много гайдов по чистке хранилища. Для каждого браузера.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Local Storage</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <textarea id="area" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  
    <script>
      const area = document.getElementById("area");
      const button = document.getElementById("clear");
      const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "ls-key";

      area.value = localStorage.getItem('area');

      area.addEventListener("input", function() {
        
  
        localStorage.setItem('area', area.value);
  
      });
  
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        localStorage.clear()
  
        document.getElementById("area").value.reset();
  
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```